# Добавить перезапись в массив с++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Всем привет. Задание такое: *Написать программу на языке С++ для создания динамического массива A[N] , заполнить  массив с помощью генератора случайных чисел (получение случайного числа в интервале [a,b]  оформить как функцию (а=-30,b =30)).  Полученный массив перезаписать, добавив к  нему (в начало) максимальное значение среди всех элементов массива. Для перезаписи использовать вспомогательный второй массив не разрешается.
Вычисление максимального значения среди всех элементов массива оформить как функцию.*
В общем нужно только добавить перезапись для подсчета максимального значения среди всех элементов массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int generateInt(int a, int b) {
    return rand() % (b - a + 1) + a; //генератора случайных чисел в интервале[a, b]
}
    
    int rewriteArray(int *A, int i) {
        // перезапись
    }
    
    int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    int const N = 10; //размер массива
    int *A = new int[N]; //выделяю память для динамического массива
    int a = -30, b = 30; //интервал[a, b] для генератора случайных чисел

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = generateInt(a,b);
        cout << rewriteArray(A,i) << endl;
    }

    delete [] A; //очищаю память
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если массив длиной n+1 cделать, то будет полегче, наверное?

Comment: `перезапись для подсчета максимального значения` э - нет, это разные задачи, для поиска максимального вам задано функцию написать.